# Deploying new version of MySQL Schema w/ Doctrine

Tags: mysql, deployment, doctrine-orm

According to the Doctrine docs, the cli schema tool should not be used to update the production database. This was a surprise to me, since one of the major selling points of doctrine was the ability to version control the database.  [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation):

> SchemaTool can do harm to your database. It will drop or alter tables,
>   indexes, sequences and such. Please use this tool with caution in
>   development and not on a production server. It is meant for helping
>   you develop your Database Schema, but NOT with migrating schema from A
>   to B in production. A safe approach would be generating the SQL on
>   development server and saving it into SQL Migration files that are
>   executed manually on the production server. SchemaTool assumes your
>   Doctrine Project uses the given database on its own. Update and Drop
>   commands will mess with other tables if they are not related to the
>   current project that is using Doctrine. Please be careful!

I'm not familiar with generating a migration schema in MySQL.  How can I automate the deployment of a new version of a production MySQL database that I've been managing in dev with Doctrine's cli tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Doctrine Project (which is not just an ORM but also a collection of related projects) has a separate project for this, called Migrations. It seems to be aimed at safer deployments with options such as generating a SQL dump file, creating versions, rollback, etc.

Here's the currently working [link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html).